# Was it illegal to express sympathy for Nazi Germany during WW2 in Great Britain?

Tags: world-war-two, united-kingdom, britain

**Was it illegal to express sympathy for Nazi Germany during WW2 in Great Britain?**

Say you are a citizen and you want your goverment to make peace with Hitler. You even want GB to become a puppet state like France did. Were you allowed to say so in public and start a campaign asking politicans to do this?

Or would this have been illegal, since you are supporting an enemy during war?

I assume it would have been illegal, but I just found fines for breaking the blackout law or not helping in the (war) industry. What would be the punishment? In Nazi Germany it would be called "[Wehrkraftszersetzung](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wehrkraftzersetzung)" (destroying the war ability) and be punishable by death.

- Breaking the law during WWII, *[BBC.com](https://www.bbc.com/news/uk-england-33566789)*
- WW2 People's War, *[bbc.co.uk](https://www.bbc.co.uk/history/ww2peopleswar/stories/60/a2316160.shtml)*

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It was contrary to regulations.  [Sir Oswald Mosely](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oswald_Mosley) was charged under   [Defense Regulation 18B](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Defence_Regulation_18B).

That said, it was possible to express anti-war opinions; lawful [opposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opposition_to_World_War_II#:%7E:text=In%20Britain%2C%20Oswald%20Mosley%20and,%22fight%20for%20Britain%20alone%22.) existed.

Although the question doesn't ask, @sempaiscuba is correct to point out that expressing opposition wasn't a capital offense; Sir Oswald was interned, but not executed.  (I'm not enough of a legal scholar to discuss the boundaries between expressing an opinion contrary to Defense Regulation 18b, Sedition and Treason. As I understand it only the last was a capital offense).

Comment: Perhaps worth mentioning that expressing support for Nazi Germany was not a capital offence during WW2, and that the punishment was usually just internment.

Comment: Might be worth pointing out that though it was against the law and you could be put in jail for it, it wasn't a 'crime' like in Germany. When the war was over the remaining internees were all released. Mosley among others was released before the war had ended.

Comment: Sedition would require actively promoting subversive views in some way, such as organising meetings or circulating leaflets. Treason would require some positive action to benefit the enemy.